# Injection of mocked service fails for nested service when testing an Angular app with ng-mocks

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, mocking, ng-mocks

We started using the very nice ng-mocks for our test, but I have trouble getting the mock injection right for this case:

- `OurService` that uses the `DatetimeService` and `NumberFormatterService`.
- `NumberFormatterService` also uses the `DatetimeService`.
- `DatetimeService` should be mocked.

Does sound that complicated, or?

Here's the (simplyfied) code:

```js
describe('OurService', () => {
  MockInstance.scope();

  let service: OurService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    MockInstance(DatetimeService, 'locale', () => 'en-US');

    await MockBuilder(OurService)
      .mock(DatetimeService)
      .provide(NumberFormatterService);

    service = TestBed.inject(OurService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  test('test setup is correct', () => {
    expect(TestBed.inject(DatetimeService).locale()).toEqual('en-US'); // works
    expect(service.datetimeService.locale()).toEqual('en-US'); // works
    expect(service.numberFormatter.datetimeService.locale()).toEqual('en-US'); // <== this fails, locale is undefined
  });
});
```

When I debug and have a breakpoint inside `locale()`, it gets called for the first two `expect()` lines, but *not* for the third. In this case simply `undefined` is returned. Which surprises me, as this must be some plain mock and not the one modified by MockInstance - and also not the original service.

Any idea or suggestion how to get this right?

Of course, I could work around and mock the `NumberFormatterService` here, but in this case I'd like to keep the original implementation to check that the services work together correctly.

In case it matters: We use jest. And here are the versions we use:

```
"jest": "^29.7.0",
"jest-preset-angular": "14.0.0",
"@nx/jest": "17.2.8",
"ng-mocks": "^14.12.1",
"@angular/core": "17.1.0",
```

As noted in the comment, this issue seems to happen only *sometimes*.

Comment: Interesting: Today I ran the same code again and it works now as expected. Maybe this was a caching issue?

Comment: In fact, a colleague is now experiencing the same problem ... sometimes ...!?